# Auto layout não funciona no Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, storyboard

Abri meu projeto que estava em Xcode 6 no Xcode 7 e o auto layout (para dispositivos diferentes) não esta funcionando no simulador. Abaixo coloco uma imagem do simulador no iphone 4s e outra no iphone 6. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Obrigado.

[image: iPhone 4S]

[image: iPhone 6]

Comment: Note que são dimensões diferentes para cada um dos simuladores que você mencionou. Se o *autolayout* está ativado e as *constraints* devidamente definidas, não teria motivo para isso acontecer. Então, baseado somente nas imagens, minha opinião é de que as *constraits* não estão corretas. Se puder nos mostrar como elas estão, poderemos ajudar mais. E isso não é por causa do `Xcode 7`, pois o simulador do iPhone 6 já vem desde o ano passado.

Comment: Oi Paulo, na verdade não defini contrains. No Xcode 6 funcionava. Ele aumentava a tela no iPhone 6 para compatibilizar o layout com o iPhone 4, por exemplo

Comment: Entendo que isso não ocorre mais no Xcode 7.

Comment: @CelsoMelero de uma olhada na minha resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91064/layout-com-largura-100-e-ou-altura-10/91069#91069

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão no XCode 7, usa-se constraints, que obriga o compilador a criar um "tamanho de tela" para cada resolução de aparelhos do iPhone.