# Layout com largura 100% e/ou altura 10%

Tags: ios, swift, layout

Como  posso aplicar em minha aplicação para deixar a largura e/ou altura em 100% para iphone e Ipad?
tenho em minha aplicação navbar. textview, webview...
obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Para criar um layout que seja compativel com Iphone e Ipads é necessario ter o conhecimento de `Auto Layout`.

Primeira coisa a ser definida na `size class` é a compatibilidade, nessa imagem ela seria para todos os dispositivos.
[image: size class]

Na sua storyboard será necessario adicionar `Constraints` para cada componente pegar a sua altura e largura exemplo:

[image: constrains]
Selecionei as duas views green and yellow e adicionei uma constraint que fazem as duas possuirem a mesma largura, desta forma quando o dispositivo for Ipad ele se adaptará.

Aconselho dar uma estudada: [Raywenderlich - Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Comment: Ok amigo, mas preciso que seja ajustado pois quando coloco o tamanho no iphone não da certo, ele corta parte....

Comment: @AugustoFurlan leia esta parte "desta forma quando o dispositivo for Ipad ele se adaptará." isso serve para qualquer outro dispositivo, faça isso que funciona... valew